# Cant get AD User name in Orchard

Tags: iis, orchardcms, orchard-modules

I tried to get Active Directory username in orchard module, but instead I get IIS APPPOOL\orchardcms

The code I'm using in the controller working fine in the ORchard source code but when I deploy it in the IIS server it resulting and IIS username instead of active directory username.

In the controller

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        ViewBag.ADUserName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;


        return View();
    }
```

Inthe View

> Welcome, @ViewBag.ADUserName

Answer (score 0):

In views you can simply write

```
@User.Identity.Name
```

to get the name of the current user.

Comment: All I'm getting is orchard username instead

Comment: I read online, it says I have to disable anonymous in IIS setting but when I disable anonymous authentication, the orchard stop working

Comment: You need to install the module AlexZh.WindowsAuthentication , see http://gallery.orchardproject.net/Packages/Orchard.Module.AlexZh.WindowsAuthentication/1.1

Comment: Also see recent question about AD users in Orchard, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44927245/orchard-cms-with-windows-auth