# Orchard CMS with windows auth?

Tags: iis, orchardcms

Can Orchard work with AD and Windows authentication?
I need to allow only specific AD groups access to a blog.  The rest of the site should be accessible to any valid domain user.  The admin dashboard should only be accessible by another specific AD group.

[ **update** ]
At the suggestion of ViRuSTriNiTy, I tried the following:
- install the windowsauth module
http://gallery.orchardproject.net/Packages/Orchard.Module.AlexZh.WindowsAuthentication
- in the admin settings, I added a user for myself as "my-domain\my-user-name", where the domain name and user are mine.
- added a role to match a AD role that I am a member of and gave this role access to everything.
- switched the iis settings over to use windows auth, and turned off anonymous
- updated the web.config to use windows auth and specify the role that I setup previous

However,I cant get to the admin panel now.  What could I be missing?

[ **update 2** ]
After noticing the documentation link he provided (duh), I saw that I needed to enable windows auth for the modules.  So I enabled IIS anonymous again (so I could log in), and updated the settings for the modules, but I see no option under Settings\Users for to enable windows auth.  Did it move? 
Im using v1.10.2

Comment: Maybe you know this already but: You'd need to implement your own version of `IMembershipService`. There's an old plugin that does this [for Dynamic CRM](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/Packages/Orchard.Module.DynamicsCRM), we've taken that code and modified it successfully for our own needs years ago. So it's certainly possible to customize the authentication process.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the module [AlexZh.WindowsAuthentication](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/Packages/Orchard.Module.AlexZh.WindowsAuthentication).

Documentation: http://orchardwinauth.codeplex.com/documentation

First you need to change the Orchard.Web project properties (in Visual Studio, click on project + F4) to ...

```
Anonymous Authentication: Disabled
Windows Authentication: Enabled
```

... and then you need to change the `Orchard.Web\Web.config`to something like this

```
  <authentication mode="Windows">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Users/Account/AccessDenied" timeout="2880" />
  </authentication>
  <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="YourDomain\Domain Users" />
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
```

The permissions can be configured as usual based on Orchard roles.

I've been using this module since 2 years now and i'm pretty happy with it but be aware that the module has several *bugs*:

- it might cause a deadlock, see https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/7688
- it creates a new user when the logged in domain user cannot be found in the Orchard DB, you might want to alter the class `CustomAuthenticationService` to avoid this (i can provide some code if you need it)

Comment: thank you.  I tried this module but I cant get to the admin panel. See updates to original post.

Comment: @bitshift Please don't edit your question when refering to my answer, it gets confusing really quick if we continue this way. I think you can't login because you created a user with name `my-domain\my-user-name`. The user name must not contain the domain. So `my-user-name` would be the right choice. Additionally this Orchard user must have a Orchard role assigned that has admin permissions.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy - does this mean that if the website is accessed by users from multiple domains that it would be possible to give a domain1\John.Smith admin permissions and at the same time be granting a potentially different human being at domain2\John.Smith admin permissions erroneously? (sorry - I know this was a long time ago...! but just planning something :) )

Comment: @TomPerren Most likely, yes. My suggestion would be to do some changes in the AlexZH code to respect the domain or you try another module like https://github.com/moov2/Orchard.ActiveDirectoryAuthorization